# Pass substitution variable to nested script

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a situation where I have a number of scripts that I need to run consecutively under the one connection. Some of the scripts require human input at runtime. The way I have organised this is that I have a Windows batch file which prompts the user for the required parameters. That batch file then passes the acquired parameter values to the SQL script.

The problem is that the variable values aren't getting to the nested script. If I bypass the intermediate script it works fine. It seems as though the problem is in proxying the values to the second.

See below for a compelte test case. In my example I am only calling one nested Script (Script1.sql). However, in a real world scenario I would potentially have multiple of these scripts.

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  TEST_ID     NUMBER,
  CREATED_BY  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
)
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEST_TABLE
   (TEST_ID, CREATED_BY)
 Values
   (1, 'FirstUser');
Insert into TEST_TABLE
   (TEST_ID, CREATED_BY)
 Values
   (2, 'SecondUser');
Insert into TEST_TABLE
   (TEST_ID, CREATED_BY)
 Values
   (3, 'ThirdUser');
COMMIT;
```

**Windows Batch File (TEST_BAT.bat)**

```
:begin 
@ECHO oFF
cls
set /p SID=DB_SID:
set /p USER=USER:
set /p USERPASS=USER PASS:
set /p NEW_USER_NAME=NEW USER NAME:
ECHO %SID%
ECHO %USER%
sqlplus %USER%/%USERPASS%@%SID% @TEST_SCRIPTS.sql %NEW_USER_NAME%
ECHO.
```

**Master SQL Script (TEST_SCRIPTS.sql)**

```
SET PAGESIZE 100
SET DEFINE OFF
SET SCAN OFF
SET FEEDBACK ON
SPOOL INSTALL_LOG.txt
@'Script1.sql' &1
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

**Nested Script 1 (Script1.sql)**

```
SET PAGESIZE 100
SET DEFINE OFF
SET SCAN OFF
SET FEEDBACK ON
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CREATED_BY='&1';
COMMIT;
```

So, in summary - what am I doing wrong in getting the substitution parameter to the nested Script

Comment: Thanks Tomás.  I just hoped to confirm, is the problem that the update sets everything to `&1` instead of the passed-in argument, or that it prompts to enter the value for the variable?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @alexgibbs. Yes, that was the problem and thank you - the problem was indeed the SET DEFINE OFF as you outlined below. I thought I had played around with removing that at some point but obviously not! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure from your post whether the problem was that the script prompts for `&1` to be input, or whether the value *&1* is being written for `CREATED_BY` instead of the provided command-line arg.

If the latter, this problem may be related to using `SET DEFINE OFF` prior to accessing the arg rather than the structure of the scripts themselves.  (By the way `SET SCAN` is obsolete).

Using your example table and scripts unaltered, I get the below (with sql-plus 12.2):

```
sqlplus myuser/mypass@mydatabase @TEST_SCRIPTS.sql VOLTRON


SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 31 12:58:46 2017

3 rows updated.
Commit complete.

SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;

TEST_ID  CREATED_BY  
1        &1          
2        &1          
3        &1
```

But, if one drops the `SET DEFINE OFF` (and `SET SCAN OFF`), the substitutions take place, as below:

```
sqlplus myuser/mypass@mydatabase @TEST_SCRIPTS.sql VOLTRON

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 31 13:11:53 2017
old   1: UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CREATED_BY='&1'
new   1: UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CREATED_BY='VOLTRON'

3 rows updated.
Commit complete.
```

Now the replacement has been passed through into the inner script.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;

TEST_ID  CREATED_BY  
1        VOLTRON     
2        VOLTRON     
3        VOLTRON
```